# "Unable to compile" error code with LEGO EV3 Arm Robot Program

Tags: ev3

Does anyone know how to fix this error with my LEGO EV3 program?

```
Unable to compile some documents for deployment:  
Program.ev3p: Use of a block which no longer exists.  
INI.ev3p: A My Block cannot contain a copy of itself.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the key phrase is "A My Block cannot contain a copy of itself." Look in the "INI" My Block for another copy of the "INI" My Block and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have nested INI inside INI maybe cause you were trying to use recursion which EV3 does not support. It might also be that you have a copy of INI inside INI not connected to the play button script.

It may also be that your INI block contains another my block inside which contains the INI block in it and so on.

It would help if you uploaded the program or showed us snapshots.